# interleaved vs multiphase buck

Tags: buck, split-phase

I understand the benefit for a interleaved buck as you can reduce the output ripple and components size, as shown by the [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva882b/slva882b.pdf?ts=1678645439028&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) reference design below:
[image]

However when looking at the [LT two phase controller](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc7821.html#product-overview) they placed the switching mosfet in series rather than parallel:
[image]

with M1&M3 and M2&4  switching simultaneously. What are the benefits of having the mosfet in series rather than parallel as shown in the first screenshot?

Comment: It looks like M1 and M2 are a charge pump and M3/M4 behave as a normal buck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scheme outlined in the LT chip can use lower voltage devices which may be helpful .What will be helpful is lower switching losses which the scheme gives. The  gate drive is more complex but that is done for you in the LT chip.Both ideas are good for input and output ripple.